# "\u0130".toLowerCase() has length 2 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8

Looks like the following code tells the length of the lower case of '\u0130' is 2. Anyone knows why?

```js
var x = '\u0130';
alert(x + ' ' + x.length + ' ' + x.toLowerCase() + ' ' + x.toLowerCase().length);
```

Comment: I think that's because \u0130 is a special character or two.

Comment: UTF characters can be 1 to 4 bytes in size taking up 1 to 4 "standard" character spaces (1 byte).

Comment: @marekful thats even the case for the initial character. The problem is, that the lowercase character consists of two characters (not bytes), `LATIN SMALL LETTER I` and `COMBINING DOT ABOVE`

Comment: @artgb, how to get the length of a utfstring when it is decoded into unicode using 'UTF-8'?

Comment: @marekful, I don't think .length returns the byte length, since '\u0130'.length is 1.

Comment: When I run this in Chrome Console, I get `İ 1 i̇ 2`. No double character here.

Comment: You don't _see_ the second character. Its a combining character. Print out `getCodepointAt(1)` and see http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=775&mode=decimal

Comment: @KanLi `.length` returns the character length in UTF16 encoding, FYI.

Comment: OK, I see your point. Yes, I've come across those invisible characters that modify or combine with the previous. But what is your question?

Comment: @tkausl, that's interesting. Why does a unicode character's lower case become 2 unicode characters? Is there a way to handle such corner cases? I have a program that does some string manipulation ignore case so I did a toLowerCase(), and this makes the code difficult to write.

Comment: Why downvote? Isn't the JS behavior here super crappy? Python doesn't have the same issue:

Comment: @KanLi Python: https://ideone.com/Vp0wBU

Comment: @makekful. The character set is Unicode. UTF-8 and UTF-16 are two of several encodings for Unicode. JavaScript (and Java, .NET, VB4+, VBA, Win32, NTFS,…) use UTF-16. UTF-16 encodes a Unicode codepoint in exactly one or two code units. UTF-16 code units are two bytes (16 bits). So, 1 and 3 bytes aren't possible in UTF-16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specifically tell the computer you're using Turkish or Azerbaijani, it uses the *default case conversion* tables. This maps LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE to LATIN SMALL LETTER I + COMBINING DOT ABOVE, not because it makes sense in any language (you haven't specified!), but because someone decided it was a reasonable default. After all, there's a combining dot above in both of them.

If you *do* specifically tell the computer you're using Turkish or Azerbaijani, then you just get the small letter *i*.

Comment: I buy your explanation, but it is super crappy if you find that `'\u0130'.toLowerCase().toUpperCase().length == 2`.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like: [...'\u0130'].length;

But, keep in mind that this won't always work 100% of the time. There's a good explanation here:

https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-strings-and-unicode-in-depth

Comment: That only has any difference for characters above 0xFFFF