# How to write strip prefix ignore case in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8

I'd like to implement a function in Javascript that given a string `s` and a string `prefix`, if `s` starts with `prefix` ignore case, then return `s` with the `prefix` stripped, otherwise return `s`.

Sounds super easy, right? Someone could just suggest

```
if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix.toLowerCase())) {
  return s.substr(prefix.length);
}
return s;
```

This won't work due to the issue mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46944497/u0130-tolowercase-has-length-2-in-javascript). Anyone has an idea how to solve it?

Comment: can you give an example of a string/prefix where this does not work?

Comment: @andi, `s='\u0130'`, and `prefix='\u0130'.toLowerCase()`, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient, but it seems to work by going character by character:

```
if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith(p.toLowerCase())) {
    var a = [];
    while (s.toLowerCase().length > p.toLowerCase().length) {
        a.unshift(s.slice(-1));
        s = s.slice(0, -1);
    }
    return a.join('');
}
return s;
```